# Find triple words in a word list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The comparative form of the adjective big is bigger, and the superlative form is biggest. I would like to prints out all such triples (early, earlier, earliest) or (hard, harder, hardest),...

I'm using Python to open wordList.txt that consists of about 5000 words. I tested my code on a small file perfectly, but it cannot run on the large file since the loops are too long.

```
def puzzleA(wordList):
    tempList1 = []
    tempList2 = []
    tempList3 = []
    for word in wordList:
        if word[-2:]=='er':
            tempList1.append(word)
        if word[-3:]=='est':
            tempList2.append(word)            

    for word1 in wordList:
        for word2 in tempList1:
            if word1==word2[:-2]:
                tempList3.append(word1)
    for word1 in tempList3:
        for word2 in tempList2:
            if word1==word2[:-3]:
                print('{}, {}er, {}'.format(word1,word1,word2))
```

Can you guys suggest another algorithm to optimize the run time please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a `dict` with the root of the words as keys, and all variations in a list as value. Then we only keep the entries with 3 values. This way, we only iterate once on the list, and once on the dict we created, keeping the whole process O(n).

We can use a `defaultdict` to build the dict more easily. Note that the `root` function might need some improvement, check your list of English adjectives!

```
from collections import defaultdict


def root(word):
    if len(word) < 4:
        return word
    if word[-3:] == 'ier':
        return word[:-3] + 'y'
    elif word[-4:] == 'iest':
        return word[:-4] + 'y'
    elif word[-2:] == 'er':
        return word[:-2]
    elif word[-3:] == 'est':
        return word[:-3]
    else:
        return word

def find_triples(words):
    out_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for word in words:
        out_dict[root(word)].append(word)

    # keep only the lists with 3 distinct values, sorted by length
    out = [sorted(set(values), key=len) for values in out_dict.values() 
                                   if len(set(values))==3]
    return out


data = ['early', 'earlier', 'earliest', 'or', 'hard', 'harder', 'hardest', 'ignored']
print(find_triples(data))
# [['early', 'earlier', 'earliest'], ['hard', 'harder', 'hardest']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Thierry. I post a comment below, hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for posting Thierry Lathuille. It's been 4 hours now since I looked at your answer. I am not good enough to understand your codes. I did adjust the root(word) function like this:

```
def root(word):
    if len(word) < 4:
        return word
    if word[-3:] == 'ier':
        return word[:-3] + 'y'
    elif word[-4:] == 'iest':
        return word[:-4] + 'y'
    elif word[-2:] == 'er':
        if word[-4:-3]==word[-3:-2]:
            return word[:-3]
        else:
            return word[:-2]
    elif word[-3:] == 'est':
        if word[-4:-3]==word[-5:-4]:
            return word[:-4]        
        return word[:-3]
    else:
        return word
```

But it has 2 problems right now:
First, the wordlist has duplicated word, so it produces something like [terry, terry, terrier].

Second, it's really difficult to find such triple [big, bigger, biggest]

Mine produces [whin, whiner, whinner], [willy, willier, willyer], [slat, slater, slatter],...

Assume that I am not allowed to remove the duplicate words first. So is there any way to access each value in each key. I'd like to compare those pair values to eliminate unwanted results.

And Thierry, if you have time, can you explain this code please?

```
out = [sorted(values, key=len) for values in out_dict.values() if len(values)==3]
```

I am really bad at reading a list comprehension.

Comment: To read list comprehensions, flip them: put the `for` part first, then the `if` part, and then imagine the expression before the `for` is `append`ed to some list. e.g. the above is equivalent to: `out = []; for similar_words in out_dict.values(): if len(similar_words) == 3: out.append(sorted(similar_words, key=len)`. Remember that each value in the dict is actually the list of words sharing the same root (it's a dict-of-lists).

Comment: You can work around the duplicate words issue by using `set` instead of `list` as the container in the dict; e.g. use `defaultdict(set)` instead of `defaultdict(list)`. This way, instead of `appending` a word to the appropriate `list` in the dict according to its root, you'll `add` it to a `set`, which will automatically discard duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much Avish.

Comment: As for your second problem, you're getting into the general problem of stemming now. For your case, it might be sufficient to have a few more stemming rules:  remove "e" from the end of words as part of their stemming, so that "fine, finer, finest" would all stem to "fin"; replace "y" with "i" at ends of words, so that "tiny, tinier, tiniest" would all stem to "tini"; remove repeated letters at end of word, so that "big, bigger, biggest" would all stem to "big". Note that it doesn't matter if the root ends up as a valid word or not; you're just using it to group together similar words.

Comment: ```out = [sorted(values, key=len) for values in out_dict.values() if len(values)==3]```         Can I ask, sorted these values doesn't work for ['ret', 'retest', 'retter'] because both have the same 6 letters. Can we sort by alphabet?

Comment: "ret", "retest", "retter" is an invalid triplet: you should either have "ret", "retter", "rettest" or "ret", "reter", "retest". If your stemming logic is correct, the triplets should never include words of the same length: one will be the root, another will be with a 2-letter suffix "er", and a third will be with a 3-letter suffix "est".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're now struggling with how to stem words in a consistent manner.
For your scenario, you can make do with a list of pattern-replacement rules, i.e. "if the word ends with *this* pattern, replace it with *that*". 
Using regular expressions, you can easily specify the patterns and replacements, including things like "if it ends with a repeating letter, replace it with a single instance of that letter".

For example:

```py
def root(word):
  pattern_replacements = [
    ("e$", ""),    # fine => fin (to match finer, finest)
    ("y$", "i"),   # tiny => tini (to match tinier, tiniest)
    ("er$", ""),
    ("est$", ""),
    (r"([a-z])\1$", r"\1")  # bigger => big 
  ]

  for pattern, replacement in pattern_replacements:
    word = re.sub(pattern, replacement, word)

  return word


words = "big bigger biggest tiny tinier tiniest fine finer finest same samer samest good gooder goodest".split(" ")
map(root, words)
# ['big', 'big', 'big', 'tini', 'tini', 'tini', 'fin', 'fin', 'fin', 'sam', 'sam', 'sam', 'good', 'good', 'good']
```

Comment: You missed a comma after ("y$", "i"). The root function works really good. I did adjust my find_triples function and both works now. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the missing comma

Comment: You're welcome. But since this is just a variation/optimization of @Thierry Lathuille's answer, I think that answer should marked as the best answer rather than this one.